# Proprietary nvidia 310m driver - temperature issues?

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, proprietary

Please help me. I have ubuntu 14.04. When I use nouveau driver gpu temperature don't up more then 70°C. But when I switch to nvidia-331-proprietary my temperature jump to 90°C or even higher when start 3D app's. I have lenovo g560, nvidia 310m, without optimus.

Comment: Of course the proprietary drivers can use the features of your card better and generate a higher usage and therefore a higher temperature, but 90°C is shortly before smoke... You should check your cooling system (fans, heat sink, thermal paste, whatever... Start with a vacuum cleaner).

Comment: Take a [full system back-up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (choose User type 4) and then use [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers- to install the NVidia drivers.  The 346.47 runs about 10°C cooler then the 331...  Leave a comment @Fabby if that wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running:

```
nvidia-settings
```

And under the PRIME Profiles tab on the left of the Nvidia settings window switch to your Intel GPU instead of Nvidia GPU. This will turn off the graphics card and help with cooling, but isn't going to help with cooling when you want to use the graphics card.

Though you can change settings there to limit how much power the graphics card will use.